# Insert Into MYSQL result duplicate records

Tags: mysql

My query :

```
insert into fakjual_detail(no_fakjual,date_fakjual,id_cur,vehicle_id,price_fakjual,qty_fakjual,amount_fakjual,ppn_fakjual,total_fakjual,bap_fakjual,sta_fakjual_det,act_fakjual_det,id_user)
select nofakjual,datefakjual,idcur,vehicle_id,price_spk,qty_spk,amountfakjual,ppnfakjual,totalfakjual,bapfakjual,stafakjualdet,actfakjualdet,iduser from spk_detail 
where spk_detail.`no_spk` = nospk
```

The query is run well if table spk_detail only have one record. the problem is when table spk_detail have two records then the record that I insert to fakjual_detail will be 4 records (2 each from table spk_detail)

Ex : 
table spk_detail have record Apple, Orange for Fruit, then result on fakjual_detail will be Apple, Orange, Apple, Orange

**UPDATE**
Table Structure :

```
spk_detail : vehicle_id, no_spk, price_spk

fakjual_detail : id_fakjualdet (auto increment), vehicle_id, price_jual
```

I Want to insert the vehicle_id and price_spk from spk_detail to fakjual_detail where no_spk = nospk (parameter from vbnet)

Please help. sorry for my bad english. Thank you

Comment: what are the primary keys in fakjual_detail and spk_detail tables?

Comment: fakjual_detail have id_fakjualdet as primary (auto increment), spk_detail have no_spk as primary with the parameter value is from program vb

Comment: tell me, do all of your 'fruits' should come with different vehicle_id?

Answer (score 0):

use limit on select query...using limit only one record is selected for that no_spk

```
insert into fakjual_detail(no_fakjual,date_fakjual,id_cur,vehicle_id,price_fakjual,qty_fakjual,amount_fakjual,ppn_fakjual,total_fakjual,bap_fakjual,sta_fakjual_det,act_fakjual_det,id_user) select nofakjual,datefakjual,idcur,vehicle_id,price_spk,qty_spk,amountfakjual,ppnfakjual,totalfakjual,bapfakjual,stafakjualdet,actfakjualdet,iduser from spk_detail  where spk_detail.`no_spk` = nospk limit 1
```

**EDIT:-**Use **group by** cause instead of limit

Comment: I already tried limit. but the result on fakjual_detail is become Apple, Apple. Not Apple and orange like I need :(. Please help

Comment: still cant solve the problem. the result still Apple, Apple. Not Apple, Orange

Comment: provide your table structure and some test data...so that we can understand your problem correctly

Comment: I already updated the table structure. please suggest. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to understand context of your question based on the input given. still i will make a effort. Did u tried using **distinct keyword** to remove duplicates. refer these http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html && http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-distinct-keyword.htm for understanding.